# How to run normal R script in all nodes of cluster/local machine (Parallel Processing)

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I have 4 different functions which am currently running serially but it is consuming lot of time. My local system has 4 cores. How to run these 4 functions in all 4 cores parallel. Example: Function 1 in core 1, Function 2 in core 2 etc.. 
Note: These 4 functions are independent.

I have tried below code from library parallel but found no significant difference in execution time. Please help

```
library(parallel)
 cl <- makeCluster(4)

 clusterExport(cl, varlist=c("foo", "foo1", "foo2", "foo3"))
 cores <- seq_along(cl)

clusterApply(cl[cores], cores, function(core) {
   if (core == 1) {
     foo(5, 4)
   } else if (core == 2) {
     foo1(5, 3)
   } else if (core == 3) {
     foo2(5, 4)
   } else if (core == 4) {
     foo3(5, 2)
   }
 })

stopCluster(cl)
```

Comment: This looks like a reasonable way to execute functions in parallel. How long did this example take to execute in parallel?

Comment: It is difficult to say something without the functions `c("foo", "foo1", "foo2", "foo3")`, i.e. a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

This can be handled using the core Future API provided by the [future](https://cran.r-project.org/package=future) package (disclaimer: I'm the author).

Here's the gist:

```
library(future)
plan(multisession)  ## all cores by default

## Launch functions asynchronously via futures
f0 <- future(foo(5, 4))
f1 <- future(foo1(5, 3))
f2 <- future(foo2(5, 4))
f3 <- future(foo3(5, 2))

## Wait for their values
v0 <- value(f0)
v1 <- value(f1)
v2 <- value(f2)
v3 <- value(f3)
```

Instead of explicit `future()/value()` calls, you can use so called future assignments to achieve the same thing:

```
library(future)
plan(multisession)  ## all cores by default

v0 %<-% foo(5, 4)
v1 %<-% foo1(5, 3)
v2 %<-% foo2(5, 4)
v3 %<-% foo3(5, 2)

## wait for, say, v2 only when you actually "need" the value
print(v2)
```